# Animated sci-fi series from 2000s involving an evil military organisation that the protagonist was trying to sabotage

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

I'm looking for an animated sci-fi series from the early 2000s.
It involved an evil military organisation of some kind and the protagonist was trying to sabotage them or was a double agent or something similar.
I remember they all wore the same kind of mask/uniform and you didn't really know who was underneath the masks. I also remember their "base" looked like Mayan pyramids.

Another detail that may be just in dubbed version was that the organisation had a salute and they shouted something like "We are Brothers Tanner" (this might not be fully accurate since it's a translation of a dub).

It had a really distinctive look, somewhere between anime and western animation, but I remember that it was all dark colours (blacks and reds). The main bad guy also wore a mask and a dark red cloak/robe.

In talking to a friend who also remembers seeing it, we think it might have been French or German.

Comment: https://seikonnoqwaser.fandom.com/wiki/Seikon_No_Qwaser_Wiki

Comment: No, that's not the one. What I'm looking for had a way more Western animation look.

Comment: You could have a look through the https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FacelessGoons page and see if any of the cartoons there match.

Comment: Hmm, I dug through the lists on TV tropes, but nothing seems familiar. Thanks though!

Comment: Do you remember anything about the protagonists? Or the channel on which you saw it? (Nickelodeon, Disney, etc. Not entirely sure which channels exist where you live)

Comment: I'm closing this question as a duplicate, since the identified answer matches a previous time this has been asked (if you click through, it's been asked, and accepted a couple times). Please note that this will not bar you from gaining rep from votes on it, and does not indicate that this is a bad question, just one that we've already answered.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to find it! It's called [*Chris Colorado*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Colorado) and it is indeed French.

I managed to remember that it had an opera-like opening theme song and that it had something to do with [*Chichen Itza*](https://www.history.com/topics/ancient-americas/chichen-itza#:%7E:text=Chichen%20Itza%20was%20a%20Mayan,remains%20an%20active%20archeological%20site.&text=Chichen%20Itza%20was%20named%20a,Seven%20Wonders%20of%20the%20World.) and looked for it like that.

Comment: Don't forget to accept it by clicking on the checkmark! Because it's a self-answer, you won't be able to do so until 48 hours after asking the question, but clicking on it now will let you know how much time is left.